# Rake cannot find gems in vendor/gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, capistrano, vendor

I'm trying to publish a Rails 3.1 (upgraded from 3.0) application. After submitting the code I ran

```
bundle install --path vendor/gems RAILS_ENV=production
```

It worked. I've got a directory `vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1`, in which `bin`, `cache`, `doc`, `gems` and `specifications` are located. However, when I run a rake task I've got an error:

```
$ rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
Could not find authlogic-3.0.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

It's not a problem with `authlogic`, it's both in `gems` and `specifications` directories, and it was `annotate` mentioned in the error before I removed it from the gemfile.

What can be wrong?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, Ruby 1.9.2p0, Rails 3.1 and Rake 0.9.2. The code was deployed by capistrano, `vendor` directory is placed in `shared` folder and linked in the releases.

Comment: Are you sure the version numbers match? Rails is looking for one version when bundler installed a different one?

Comment: In Ubuntu, 1.9.1 is the official name of the 1.9.2 release. Really weird, I know. All the installed programs are named like that: ruby1.9.1, gem1.9.1, irb1.9.1. And all the gems are by default placed in 1.9.1 folders. So yes, this part is correct for sure.

Comment: What about the missing gem? Did it install version 3.0.3?

Comment: Yes. `annotate` was also in the correct version when it was declared missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the project's gems then you should use `bundle exec` command e.g.,

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

also require authlogic gem in gem file.

```
gem 'authlogic'
```

First delete the whole gems directory from vendor/ folder. You should use this:

```
bundle install --path=vendor/gems
```

no needs for specifying the environment.